# QUrl and QNetworkReply errors

Tags: qt, network-programming, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest, qnetworkreply

Using Qt 5.4 32-bit on Windows 8.1 (64-bit) with MingW.

I am experiencing a weird problem. Consider this:

```
//QString m_sUrl = "cloud.mysystem.info/";
//QString m_sFileName = "results.html";
//QNetworkAccessManager m_Manager;

QUrl url(m_sURL + m_sFileName);
url.setScheme("ftp");
url.setUserName(m_sLogin);
url.setPassword(m_sPassword);

QFile *file = new QFile(m_sFileName);

if(file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_Manager.put(QNetworkRequest(url), file);

    connect(reply, static_cast<void (QNetworkReply::*)(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)>(&QNetworkReply::error), this, &OCMResults::error);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, reply, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, file, &QObject::deleteLater);
}
else
    file->deleteLater();
```

At first my code worked fine but then it stopped working (possibly due to my change, not sure what was it) and only workaround is when I write the url explicitely:

```
QNetworkReply(QUrl("ftp://" + m_sLogin + ":" + m_sPassword + "@" + m_sURL + m_sFileName)), file);
```

The resulting URL is exactly the same but for some reason when I create it beforehand and pass it to the QNetworkReply it does not take it:

```
reply.url().host()
```

yields nothing if that is the case for example. I feel like I am missing something really obvious here...

The errors are either:

```
3 (host not found) when ftp is specified in the url string
301 (unknown protocol) when I do not specify it in the url but specify it as setScheme("ftp") instead
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but could it be the port? Does manually specifying the access port help?

Comment: Your recent edit talks about a different issue and is confusing. You should probably ask a separate question.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan I just tried it with port 21 and still the same. Updated OP with some more details of the errors I am getting.

Comment: Do your errors show up only when the URL is specified in the fashion you have shown?

Comment: You could also try using the `toString()` method to check the URL generated in the two cases.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan You were right, toString() got me this: 'ftp:// login:password@:21cloud.mysystem.info/results.html' which is obviously wrong. But why it appends the port like that? And since it does it obviously misinterprets the address even without the port. But how to fix it?

Comment: Small update. When I do NOT use 'setScheme("ftp")' but have the protocol as part of the url string it works. Still no idea why.

Comment: Looks like a bug. It could probably be worked around by doing the operations in a different order.